# How to manage coordinates in a NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I'm new in Mac programming. The first thing I've noticed is that the (0, 0) coordinate in a NSView is the bottom-left corner.

I'm going to use a NSView as a canvas, to draw objects on it. My objects will be positioned from the top-left corner. I can convert Y coordinates using a geometrical transformation.

But the problem is: I'm not sure how to proceed when **the view is resized**. I don't want to calculate the layout every resize event, because calculating it takes between 150 and 250 ms.

So, to Mac experts:

1. Do you know a good practice calculating the layout based on the top-left corner?
2. How should I manage the resize behavior?
3. Do you know other techniques, flipping the graphics object, or something like that, to draw this kind of stuff?

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking. Flipping coordinate system is a trivial geometrical transformation, it can not change the way you do layout. What is the problem?

Comment: @hamstergene: The problem is that if I do the geometrical transformation in the layout, then I need to re-calculate the layout when the NSView is resized, and this could perform bad.

Comment: I haven't actually done this but….  You can subclass NSView and return YES for an implementation of `isFlipped`.  Wouldn't that let you use the coordinates you want directly?

Comment: @DanielPeñalba You will have to recalculate it regardless whether you applied transformations or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just implement 
- (void)isFlipped {
  return YES;
}

In your NSView subclass.